# Symfony 4 migration blocked by PostgreSQL issue with sequences

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine

I'm running a Symfony install on version 4.3 with PostgreSQL database version 4.12.

I modified an entity through Symfony console and get this error message when trying to execute the migration:

```
"SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERREUR: la colonne "min_value" n'existe pas 
LINE1: SELECT min_value, increment_by FROM "project"."project_id_seq"
```

I understand it has to do with how PostgreSQL works with Symfony / Doctrine, yet I have not find how to make sure they work properly together and do not throw this error.

I already have tried out this github answers :

https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/2868

And got the following error : 
Undefined index: increment_by

UPDATE :

I tried this piece of code in PostgreSqlSchemaManager.php in the function _getPortableSequenceDefinition line 292 :

```
 $version = floatval($this->_conn->getWrappedConnection()->getServerVersion());

    if ($version >= 10) {
    $data = $this->_conn->fetchAssoc('SELECT min_value, increment_by FROM pg_sequences WHERE schemaname = \'public\' AND sequencename = ' . $this->_conn->quote($sequenceName));
    } else {
        $data = $this->_conn->fetchAssoc('SELECT min_value, increment_by FROM ' . $this->_platform->quoteIdentifier($sequenceName));
    }
```

And got the following error :

```
Unsupported operand types
```

Comment: Are you sure PostgreSQL version 4.12?

Comment: I had this issue a long time ago and that was because the backup of database was from a 9.6 version of Postgres and I had 11.0

Comment: @AndreaManzi I've checked I'm on version 4.12 and specified it in the doctrine.yaml file as well, still get that min_value does not exists.

Comment: @AythaNzt how do you check your database backup version please?

Comment: If you have the dump, the version should be appear in the first line